# Handling memory with multiple workers in foreach loop

Tags: r, memory, foreach, parallel-processing

I am working on a machine with 120 kernels and 500GB memory. Since I have to perform multiple computationally extensive tasks, I use `foreach` loops and the `doSNOW` cluster to parallelize these. However, sometimes all the tasks combined allocate too much memory and thus the machine stops working.

*Is it possible to limit the used memory of all combined parallel workers? Is it possible to stop the execution of a sourced R-skript if these memory limits are exceeded?*

I would try something like this...

```
library(doSNOW)
library(foreach)

nCPUs <- 120

mem <- memory.limit()

memory.limit(size = mem/nCPUs)

cl <- makeCluster(nCPUs)
registerDoSNOW(cl)

foreach(...)%dopar% {
  ...
}
```

but the while testing, `memory.limit(size = 20000)` returns the warning

> `Warning message:
>   In memory.limit(size = 20000) : cannot decrease memory limit: ignored`

Checking if it worked reveals that the memory.limit was not reduced (as stated in the warning)

```
> memory.limit()
[1] 32692
```

Comment: What do you want to happen? A graceful R error? The OS stopping R processes? ... Typically you'd try doing some memory benchmarks in dependence of number of workers and try to extrapolate how many workers you can use. Memory limits I'd set at the OS level.

Comment: The best thing would be if the workers would stop. Thus I would be able to reduce the number of workers by adjusting `nCPUs`